# Find common matched IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

I have a table(see below) which contains a list of friends. In each row, the user can be either the sender or receiver (requestor/requestee). The status then keeps track of their relationship(a status of 1 means they are friends). But because the uid can be in either the sender or receiver, it's messing me up.

```
================================
| sender   | reciever | status |
--------------------------------
| testusr1 | testusr2 | 1      |
| testusr1 | testusr3 | 1      |
| testusr1 | testusr4 | 0      |
| testusr1 | testusr5 | 1      |
| testusr3 | testusr4 | 1      |
| testusr3 | testusr2 | 1      |
| testusr5 | testusr3 | 1      |
```

So in the above example, testusr1's friends are: testusr2, testusr3, and testusr5. 
testusr3's friends are: testusr5, testusr4, testusr2, testusr1

What I'm looking for is a query that will get the common friends: testusr2 and testusr5

Scavenging from another answer I had gotten here, i thought I could do a union, but I lost the logic I was following about halfway through...

```
SELECT f.uid
    FROM(
        (SELECT reciever as uid FROM friends where status=1 and sender='$sentuid')
        UNION 
        (SELECT sender as uid FROM friends where status=1 and reciever='$sentuid')
    ) f
    WHERE ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like - (**edited**)

```
SELECT f.uid
FROM (
     SELECT f1.reciever as uid FROM friends f1
     WHERE f1.sender = USER1 AND f1.status = 1
     UNION
     SELECT f2.sender as uid FROM friends f2
     WHERE f2.reciever = USER1 AND f2.status = 1
    ) f
WHERE f.uid IN (
     SELECT f3.reciever as uid FROM friends f3
     WHERE f3.sender = USER3 AND f3.status = 1 AND f3.reciever != USER1
     UNION
     SELECT f4.sender as uid FROM friends f4
     WHERE f4.reciever = USER3 AND f4.status = 1 AND f4.sender != USER1
    );
```

Replace the `USER1` and `USER3` with your 2 user ids that you want to find common friends

sqlfiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0aaf4/8

Answer (score 0):

**This should do the trick. [UPDATED]**

*You have to set sender and receiver values to find mutual friends. Below query will find mutual friends of Sender: testusr1 and Receiver: testusr3*

```
set @sender_value=testusr1, @receiver_value=testusr3;

SELECT
    DISTINCT
    F1.Mutual_Friends
  FROM
    (
    SELECT F.sender Mutual_Friends FROM friends F WHERE F.receiver = @sender_value AND F.status = 1
    UNION
    SELECT F.receiver Mutual_Friends FROM friends F WHERE F.sender = @sender_value AND F.status = 1
    ) F1
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT F.sender Mutual_Friends FROM friends F WHERE F.receiver = @receiver_value AND F.status = 1
    UNION
    SELECT F.receiver Mutual_Friends FROM friends F WHERE F.sender = @receiver_value AND F.status = 1
    ) F2 ON
      F2.Mutual_Friends = F1.Mutual_Friends;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.reciever 
FROM (SELECT a.sender, a.reciever 
      FROM tableA a 
      WHERE a.sender IN ('testusr1', 'testusr3') AND a.status = 1
      UNION 
      SELECT a.reciever AS sender, a.sender AS reciever 
      FROM tableA a 
      WHERE a.reciever IN ('testusr1', 'testusr3') AND a.status = 1
     ) AS A 
GROUP BY a.reciever 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.sender) > 1
```